# Help! How would you write this rhythm (audio linked below)?

Tags: notation, composition, rhythm, songwriting

The audio source [can be found here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Composers/comments/m6ljgn/how_would_you_write_the_section_in_blue_listen/). I'm interested in the section highlighted in blue.

There is naturally some freedom in the artist's interpretation, but I would like to transcribe it in a relatively precise manner. It isn't very obvious, as it seems to be partially a treble. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this bar as:

[image]

It feels similar to eighth notes with triplet swing, but I wouldn't write "swing" for a single bar.  I leave the lateness of beat 1 to interpretation.